# Docusign Integration with React Native

Tags: javascript, docusignapi

I am trying to integrate docusign with a React Native app I am building. My desired workflow is to have the user launch a remote signing envelope based on a template.

From the Node JS examples, eg009 seems to be the end result I am after. However, I am wanting to complete this with Axios/Fetch and Javascript.

My intended flow is to have the user enter in their name and email, and their spouses name and email. From there they press a submit button which sends the API call, and that is the extent of what the app does.

I am wanting the API call to then start the template flow, sending a document to sign via email to both that were entered into the app. I want the users to authorize themselves from the email, not the app. After both parties have signed, I want it sent to a third static email.

I do not want the users to have to authorize inside the app or be redirected anywhere. It seems a JWT would be best.

Does this seem possible? How would you suggest going about this?

I appreciate the help!

Comment: do you have a server or run serverless?

Comment: @InbarGazit We do not run a server, the app is compiled out to ios and android. The primary functions of the app are reliant on another API. The app itself has no database or server.

Comment: I spent a good amount of time trying to get the docusign-esign node package running in the app. But there is enough node only packages in there that attempting to get it to work became too hacky. However, getting the examples project up and running gave me an idea of how some of the calls should be.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the JWT grant flow is the right fit for you here. Please see this article for more details: https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth

Answer (score 0):

There's no good solution for running DocuSign API calls from client as a result of CORS limitations.
Larry has some blog posts on this topic - https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-building-single-page-applications-with-docusign-and-cors-part-2

You could use something like [AWS lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/?c=ser&sec=srv) which is not a server per-se, but gives you server capabilities without the hassle of a server.

Check also the [latest blog by Larry](https://www.docusign.com/blog/dsdev-building-spas-cors-react-part-3) on this topic which superficially covers using React for single-page apps.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I am thinking that I will be going a Native route using the Obj C and Java sdks and building a component for each OS that I can use in the Javascript side.

Comment: sure, you could do that, our Mobile SDKs support most of the functionality you would need. Let me know if I can help further